# Extract XML fragment to use as output with prefix mods

Tags: xml, xslt

I was trying to come up with a descriptive title... lol...

Anyway; this is probably simple but I'm struggling a bit here. I have an input that I need to process. I need to do this:

1. Extract "process" and all of its children.
2. Change all "client" NS prefixes to "fha"
3. Add base namespace to the "process" tag (yes, I know that's funky, but that's want the resource I am consuming wants.)

**Input file**

```html
<TOTALRequest-Response-Keys xmlns="http://xmlns.oracle.com/F17CTOTALScorecard/F17CTOTALScorecard/F17CTOTALScorecard">
  <fha_case_number>2812883060</fha_case_number>
  <loan_number>1000006611</loan_number>
  <score_dt>2019/01/31 16:23:55</score_dt>
  <aus>ZFWF</aus>
  <times_enqueued>1</times_enqueued>
  <TOTALRequest-Response xmlns:client="http://xmlns.oracle.com/F17CTOTALScorecard/F17CTOTALScorecard/F17CTOTALScorecard">
    <client:process>
      <client:monthly_income/>
      <!-- many elements -->
      <client:loanapp>
        <client:loanapptype>MISMOAUS2.4</client:loanapptype>
        <ns1:loanappdata xmlns="http://xmlns.oracle.com/F17CTOTALScorecard/F17CTOTALScorecard/F17CTOTALScorecard" xmlns:ns2="http://mismo.org/aus/" xmlns:ns1="http://xmlns.oracle.com/F17CTOTALScorecard/F17CTOTALScorecard/F17CTOTALScorecard">
          <ns2:LOAN_APPLICATION MISMOVersionID="2.4"/>
          <!-- many elements ns1:whatever -->
          </ns1:loanappdata>
          </client:loanapp>
     </client:process>
     <client:processResponse/>
  </TOTALRequest-Response>
</TOTALRequest-Response-Keys>
```

**Desired output**

```html
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:f17="http://xmlns.oracle.com/F17CTOTALScorecard/F17CTOTALScorecard/F17CTOTALScorecard">
<soapenv:Body>
<fha:process xmlns:fha="http://xmlns.oracle.com/F17CTOTALScorecard/F17CTOTALScorecard/F17CTOTALScorecard">
      <fha:monthly_income>
            <fha:loanapp>
        <fha:loanapptype>MISMOAUS2.4</fha:loanapptype>
        <ns1:loanappdata xmlns="http://xmlns.oracle.com/F17CTOTALScorecard/F17CTOTALScorecard/F17CTOTALScorecard" xmlns:ns2="http://mismo.org/aus/" xmlns:ns1="http://xmlns.oracle.com/F17CTOTALScorecard/F17CTOTALScorecard/F17CTOTALScorecard">
          <ns2:LOAN_APPLICATION MISMOVersionID="2.4">
        </ns1:loanappdata>
      </fha:loanapp>
    </fha:process>

 </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

**What I current;y have**

```html
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:fha="http://xmlns.oracle.com/F17CTOTALScorecard/F17CTOTALScorecard/F17CTOTALScorecard"
xmlns:client="http://xmlns.oracle.com/F17CTOTALScorecard/F17CTOTALScorecard/F17CTOTALScorecard"
xmlns:ns1="http://xmlns.oracle.com/F17CTOTALScorecard/F17CTOTALScorecard/F17CTOTALScorecard">
xmlns:ns2="http://mismo.org/aus/">

<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" omit-xml-declaration="yes" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
 <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:f17="http://xmlns.oracle.com/F17CTOTALScorecard/F17CTOTALScorecard/F17CTOTALScorecard">
 <soapenv:Body>
 <fha:process xmlns:fha="http://xmlns.oracle.com/F17CTOTALScorecard/F17CTOTALScorecard/F17CTOTALScorecard">
 <xsl:copy>
  <xsl:copy-of select="/*/*/*:process/child::*"/>
 </xsl:copy>
 </fha:process>
 </soapenv:Body>
 </soapenv:Envelope>
</xsl:template>



<!--
<xsl:template match="client:*" name="change_prefix">
 <xsl:element name="fha:{local-name()}">
  <xsl:apply-templates select="."/>
 </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>


<xsl:template match="/">
 <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:f17="http://xmlns.oracle.com/F17CTOTALScorecard/F17CTOTALScorecard/F17CTOTALScorecard">
 <soapenv:Body>
 <xsl:copy>
  <xsl:copy-of select="/*/*/child::*"/>
 </xsl:copy>
 <xsl:apply-templates select="change_prefix" />
 </soapenv:Body>
 </soapenv:Envelope>
</xsl:template>
-->
 
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I have tried a lot of things but I feel like I'm just throwing noodles at the wall. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would this work for you?

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:fha="http://xmlns.oracle.com/F17CTOTALScorecard/F17CTOTALScorecard/F17CTOTALScorecard"
xmlns:client="http://xmlns.oracle.com/F17CTOTALScorecard/F17CTOTALScorecard/F17CTOTALScorecard">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="/fha:TOTALRequest-Response-Keys">
    <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:f17="http://xmlns.oracle.com/F17CTOTALScorecard/F17CTOTALScorecard/F17CTOTALScorecard">
        <soapenv:Body>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="fha:TOTALRequest-Response/client:process"/>
        </soapenv:Body>
    </soapenv:Envelope>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="client:*">
    <xsl:element name="fha:{local-name()}">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: That comes very close. I need to exclude mods on this fragment though:

        <ns1:loanappdata xmlns="http://xmlns.oracle.com/F17CTOTALScorecard/F17CTOTALScorecard/F17CTOTALScorecard" xmlns:ns2="http://mismo.org/aus/" xmlns:ns1="http://xmlns.oracle.com/F17CTOTALScorecard/F17CTOTALScorecard/F17CTOTALScorecard">
          <ns2:LOAN_APPLICATION MISMOVersionID="2.4">
        </ns1:loanappdata>

Comment: What does the first template do?

Comment: I think I may be misunderstanding the final issue... I'm just going to mark you correct and say THANKS for now while I sort the minutia.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "exclude mods". Other than changing the `client` prefix everything is copied as is (that's what the identity transform template does).

Comment: I meant "nodes" ... not "mods" -- it was just a brainfart on my part. My static sample didn't match the live test data. I thought the transform was stripping the prefixes from the embedded document, but the test data didn't have namespace prefixes on the embedded document.

One display later and I'm feeling stupid. :)

Your sample worked perfectly. I just had to add a namespace declaration .

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that I didn't need to do anything with the embedded fragment. The endpoint was able to grasp the default namespace for the embedded document(s) (But if someone wants to respond to that I wouldn't object.)

The only change I needed to make to Michael's answer was to add a namespace declaration to the "envelope" tag. (No way Micheal could have known that another namespace was needed by the end process.)

```html
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:fha="http://xmlns.oracle.com/F17CTOTALScorecard/F17CTOTALScorecard/F17CTOTALScorecard"
xmlns:client="http://xmlns.oracle.com/F17CTOTALScorecard/F17CTOTALScorecard/F17CTOTALScorecard"
xmlns:ns2="http://mismo.org/aus/" 
xmlns:ns1="http://xmlns.oracle.com/F17CTOTALScorecard/F17CTOTALScorecard/F17CTOTALScorecard">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="/fha:TOTALRequest-Response-Keys">
    <soapenv:Envelope 
     xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" 
     xmlns:f17="http://xmlns.oracle.com/F17CTOTALScorecard/F17CTOTALScorecard/F17CTOTALScorecard"
 xmlns:fha="http://xmlns.oracle.com/F17CTOTALScorecard/F17CTOTALScorecard/F17CTOTALScorecard">
        <soapenv:Body>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="fha:TOTALRequest-Response/client:process"/>
        </soapenv:Body>
    </soapenv:Envelope>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="client:*">
    <xsl:element name="fha:{local-name()}">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```